# How to solve "unmet dependencies error" of libdrm2?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

How can I solve this issue? -f does not work for that.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm2 : Depends: libdrm-common (>= 2.4.82+git20170731.3876bc24-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```